Python pandas drop duplicates with if else condition
UPDATE
I'm sorry, my example seemed to have been not that clear. The attributes are not single columns, but one column contains all the attributes.  As shown in the example, the attributes are 1, 2, 3.
Note I simplified my example dataset. In reality I have about 60 attributes, which are not numbers.
I have a dataframe with two colums (location, attribute). Some locations are duplicated, and for those duplicates I want to keep all rows which do not have a specific value in the attribute column. However, if no other value than that specific value is available then keep the row with that certain.
location = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']
attribute = ['1', '2', '3', '2', '2']

df = pd.DataFrame({'location':location, 'attribute':attribute})


expected output:

In other words, as I have many attributes, I want to prefer all attributes before a specific one, and only if no other one is available, only then take the row with the 'unpreferred' value.
In the table it is the attrbute value 2.
How can I do that?

If I understand corretcly : df.drop_duplicates(subset="location", keep="last")

You say "which do not have a specific value in the attribute column" but you don't say what that value is to explain how you get your expected output.

@CNGF I updated my question. In reality I don't have numbers but strings.

I do not understand the last paragraph. Can you rephrase it?. Additionally, can you update your example so this "to prefer all attributes before a specific one" is captured in the example?. Edit: by preferred you mean that the attribute is only present in such location?

Goal
IIUC, for each location you want to keep all rows that are perfect as far as the attributes are concerned. When you have 0 perfect rows for a location, you want to keep the least imperfect one.
Sample

Adding an 'attribute' column, since you have more than one.
Adding a second 'perfect' row for location 'A'.

import pandas as pd

location = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']
attribute = ['1', '3', '2', '3', '2', '2']
attribute2 = ['1', '20', '2', '10', '10', '10']

df = pd.DataFrame({'location':location, 
                   'attribute':attribute,
                   'attribute2':attribute2
                   })

df

  location attribute attribute2
0        A         1          1 # keep both row 1 and row 2
1        A         3         20
2        B         2          2 # attr == 2, not preferred
3        B         3         10 # attr2 == 10, not preferred, but better
4        C         2         10 # keep just 1 row, both equally unpreferred
5        C         2         10

Code
weights = [2, 1]

attributes = (pd.concat([df['attribute'].ne('2'),
                         df['attribute2'].ne('10')
                         ], 
                        axis=1)
              .mul(weights)
              .sum(axis=1)
              )

idx_values = (attributes.groupby(df['location'])
              .agg(lambda x: x[(x==x.max())].index.tolist()
                    if x.max() == sum(weights)
                    else x.idxmax()
                    )
              .explode()
              )

out = df.iloc[idx_values]

Output
  location attribute attribute2
0        A         1          1
1        A         3         20
3        B         3         10
4        C         2         10

Explanation

First, use pd.concat to join boolean series for all attributes (on axis1).
If you have a preference for certain attributes, adjust the weights list. E.g., in this example, 'attribute' gets weighted at 2. That means: attribute != 2 is considered more important than attribute2 != 10. Put differently: in case of a tie you prefer the row with attribute2 == 10. We can add these weights with df.mul. If you have no particular sub-preferences, skip this step and immediately ask df.sum on axis=1.
Now, we take the resulting Series and apply Series.groupby, passing df.locations. If you were only interested in one match per location, we could simply get groupby.idxmax. To get duplicates for perfect locations, let's use a custom function: if the max value is equal to the sum of weights, we want all matches for idxmax, else we just get the first.
With lists in our returned series, we need to add Series.explode to get these index values in separate rows.
Finally, we can use these values to select from the original df with df.iloc.

Intermediates
pd.concat([df['attribute'].ne('2'),
                         df['attribute2'].ne('10')
                         ], 
                        axis=1)

   attribute  attribute2
0       True        True # twice all good
1       True        True
2      False        True # a False, bc `attribute == 2`
3       True       False # a False, be `attribute2 == 10`
4      False       False # twice all wrong
5      False       False

attributes

0    3 # twice max score
1    3
2    1 # `True` for attribute2 only weighs 1
3    2 # `True` for attribute weighs 2
4    0 # twice min score
5    0 
dtype: int64

idx_values

location
A    0 # both rows for 'A'
A    1
B    3 # index 3 is selected
C    4 # only one row for 'C'
dtype: object


Thank you for your work! But sorry that it is doesn't fully correspondent to my question, as I have only one column which holds all attributevalues. Still, very helpful for other situations!

As stated by @CNGF in the comments aren't you just looking for drop duplicates?
location = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']
attribute = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two']

df = pd.DataFrame({'location':location, 'attribute':attribute})

df.drop_duplicates(subset='location', keep='last', inplace=True)
print(df)

The output is:
  location attribute
0        A       one
2        B     three
4        C       two


Thank you for trying to help! Unfortuately this does not allow for including a condition statement. The problem I gave is a very simplified version of what I have, and for that I need to be able to include a condition statement (if ... then).

You can put the preferred ones into a dictionary and then create the dataframe you want.
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

location = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']
attribute = ['1', '2', '3', '2', '2']

df = pd.DataFrame({'location':location, 'attribute':attribute})

data = OrderedDict()


def best_value_seen(x, y):

    if not data.get(x):
        data[x] = y
    else:
        # some reason why x and y value is preferred
        if x and y > data[x]:
            data[x] = y


df.apply(lambda x: best_value_seen(x['location'], x['attribute']), axis=1)

answer = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'location': data.keys(), 'attribute': data.values()})
print(answer)
#  location attribute
#0        A         1
#1        B         3
#2        C         2

